# How can I create a SQL Server view that will return the results of a complex SQL that uses cursors or from a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that contains schedules and each interval is one record in that table (i.e. 8:00 to 5:00. Monday through Friday would be 5 records in that table).  I have been working on a way to easily detect duplicates in a SQL query that can be created as a view.  I have a SQL query that does the work using Cursors and a temporary table, but Cursors don't work in Views.

I've even created a Stored Procedure to populate the temporary table, but what I would really like to do is call the stored procedure from a View and show the results.

If I execute the stored procedure, it does return the expected results, however I need to be able to see the results from a Select statement. I cannot give my users the ability to execute stored procedures directly.

Here's the code for the SP.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Report_Duplicate_Schedules
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Number1 AS INT, @Count1 AS INT, @ST1 AS INT, @ET1 AS INT
    DECLARE @Number2 AS INT, @Count2 AS INT, @ST2 AS INT, @ET2 AS INT
    DECLARE @Count3 AS INT

    CREATE TABLE #SchedulesDuplicates (ScheduleName NVARCHAR(100), ScheduleNumber INT, DuplicateSchedule NVARCHAR(100), DuplicateNumber INT, StartTime INT, StopTime INT);

    DECLARE Step1 CURSOR
        FOR (SELECT DISTINCT [Number], COUNT(*) AS [Count] FROM [Schedules] GROUP BY [Number])
    OPEN Step1
    FETCH NEXT FROM Step1 INTO @Number1, @Count1
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE Step2 CURSOR
            FOR (SELECT [Number], COUNT(*) AS [Count] FROM [Schedules] WHERE [Number] > @Number1 GROUP BY [Number])
        OPEN Step2
        FETCH NEXT FROM Step2 INTO @Number2, @Count2
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            IF @Count1 = @Count2
            BEGIN
                --PRINT CAST(@Number1 AS VARCHAR(50)) + N' - ' + CAST(@Count1 AS VARCHAR(50)) + N' - ' + CAST(@Number2 AS VARCHAR(50)) + N' - ' + CAST(@Count2 AS VARCHAR(50))
                SELECT @Count3 = COUNT(*) FROM 
                (SELECT [Number], [StartTime], [StopTime] FROM [Schedules] WHERE [Number] = @Number1) AS z,
                (SELECT [Number], [StartTime], [StopTime] FROM [Schedules] WHERE [Number] = @Number2) AS y
                WHERE z.[StartTime] = y.[StartTime] AND z.[StopTime] = y.[StopTime]
                IF @Count1 = @Count3
                BEGIN
                    --PRINT CAST(@Number1 AS VARCHAR(50)) + N' - ' + CAST(@Count1 AS VARCHAR(50)) + N' - ' + CAST(@Number2 AS VARCHAR(50)) + N' - ' + CAST(@Count2 AS VARCHAR(50)) + N' - ' + CAST(@Count3 AS VARCHAR(50))
                    INSERT INTO #SchedulesDuplicates ([ScheduleName], [ScheduleNumber], [DuplicateSchedule], [DuplicateNumber], [StartTime], [StopTime]) (SELECT DISTINCT u.[Name], u.[Number], v.[Name], v.[Number], v.[StartTime], v.[StopTime] FROM (SELECT [Name], [Number], [StartTime], [StopTime] FROM [Schedules] WHERE [Number] = @Number1) AS u, (SELECT [Name], [Number], [StartTime], [StopTime] FROM [Schedules] WHERE [Number] = @Number2) AS v)
                END
            END
            FETCH NEXT FROM Step2 INTO @Number2, @Count2
        END 
        CLOSE Step2
        DEALLOCATE STEP2
        FETCH NEXT FROM Step1 INTO @Number1, @Count1
    END
    CLOSE Step1
    DEALLOCATE Step1

SELECT * FROM #SchedulesDuplicates

DROP TABLE #SchedulesDuplicates

END
GO
```

Comment: look into using a function then

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(MyServerName, 'SET FMTONLY OFF EXEC database.dbo.procedure')
```

Few notes:

- DATAACCESS option should be enabled on the server
- SET FMTONLY is mostly required for correct columns metadata retrieval
- Procedure should have SET NOCOUNT ON statement at the beginning, without it
  metadata retrieval fails

---

However I would advise you to rewrite this row by row processing logic to set based code, which would easily fit into ordinary view. Table-valued user defined function would also do the job.